# Showing that $x^{\top}Ax$ is maximized at $\max \lambda(A)$ for symmetric $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I'm hoping that someone can help me fix my proof for the following theorem:

> Given a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $A$,
>
> $$ \max_{x : ||x||_2 = 1} x^{\top}Ax = \max \lambda(A), $$
>
> where $\max \lambda(A)$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

My proof attempt:

> Let $A$ be a symmetric matrix with eigenvalue decomposition $A =
> > V\Lambda V^{\top}$. Taking the square root of $A$, we have that
>   $A^{1/2} = V\Lambda^{1/2} V^{\top}$. Thus,
>
> $$ x^{\top}Ax = x^{\top}A^{1/2}A^{1/2}x =
> > x^{\top}(A^{1/2})^{\top}A^{1/2}x = ||A^{1/2}x||_2^2. $$
>
> Recall now that $||A^{1/2}x||_2^2$ has maximum $\max
> > \lambda(A^{\top}A)$ (the largest eigenvalue of
>   $(A^{1/2})^{\top}A^{1/2} = A$), since it reduces to maximizing a
>   spectral norm.)

I realize that this proof falls apart very early on, since when I take the square root of $A$, I am assuming that it is positive semidefinite (otherwise we couldn't take the square root of $\Lambda$ over $\mathbb{R}$).

Is there a small fix that I can apply here? Or better yet, is there a more concise proof altogether?

Answer (score 3):

There is a cleaner proof altogether that circumvents the need to consider the square root of $A$. Consider the spectral decomposition of $A$ given by $A = V\Lambda V^{\top}$. For some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $\tilde{x} = V^{\top}x$. Then,

$$
x^{\top}Ax = x^{\top}V\Lambda V^{\top}x = \tilde{x}^{\top}\Lambda \tilde{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \tilde{x}_i^2.
$$

Clearly,

$$
\min \lambda(A) \sum_{i=1}^n \tilde{x}_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \tilde{x}_i^2 \leq \max \lambda(A)\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde{x}_i^2
$$

from which it follows that

$$
\min \lambda(A) \leq x^{\top}Ax \leq \max \lambda(A).
$$

(Note that since $V$ is an orthogonal matrix, $x = U\tilde{x}$, and so the above argument applies for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes.

The fix would be to add a multiple of the identity such that $A+cI$ is positive definite, since this just shifts the claimed equation by $c$ on both sides. (I didn't check your proof in detail; it seems you're missing square roots where it says $\lambda(A^\top A)$?)

The more concise proof would be to write

$$
x^\top Ax=x^\top V\Lambda V^\top x=(V^\top x)^\top\Lambda V^\top x=\sum_i\Lambda_i(V^\top x)_i^2
$$

and note that since $V^\top$ is unitary, $V^\top x$ runs through all unit vectors, and the sum is clearly maximized for $(V^\top x)_i=\delta_{i,i_\text{max}}$.