# Does maximum eigenvalue of the leading principal submatrices of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix always increase?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices

Given a symmetric tridiagonal matrix in the form of

$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x_1}}&{{y_1}}&{}&{} \\ 
  {{y_1}}&{{x_2}}& \ddots &{} \\ 
  {}& \ddots & \ddots &{{y_{n - 1}}} \\ 
  {}&{}&{{y_{n - 1}}}&{{x_n}} 
\end{array}} \right)$$

where $y_1,...,y_{n-1}$ are all positive numbers. My questions is, does the maximum eigenvalue of its leading principal submatrices $\left( {{x_1}} \right)$, $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x_1}}&{{y_1}} \\ 
  {{y_1}}&{{x_2}} 
\end{array}} \right)$, $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{x_1}}&{{y_1}}&{} \\ 
  {{y_1}}&{{x_2}}&{{y_2}} \\ 
  {}&{{y_2}}&{{x_3}} 
\end{array}} \right)$, etc. are non-decreasing? If so, which theorem states this or can be used to prove this? Thanks!!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705386/showing-that-x-topax-is-maximized-at-max-lambdaa-for-symmetric-a

Comment: The answer is yes.  We could use Cauchy's interlacing theorem