# A clarification to a proof that $x^{\top}Ax$ is maximized at $\max \lambda(A)$ for symmetric $A$

Tags: matrices

I'm looking for a clarification of an answer to

[Showing that $x^{\top}Ax$ is maximized at $\max \lambda(A)$ for symmetric $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705386/showing-that-x-topax-is-maximized-at-max-lambdaa-for-symmetric-a)

(This is a clarified formulation of my original question which I deleted)

The question at the given link asks for a proof that

> Given a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $A$,
>
> $$ \max_{x : ||x||_2 = 1} x^{\top}Ax = \max \lambda(A), $$
>
> where $\max \lambda(A)$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

I've approached solving the problem in exactly the same way as @Ryan at the above page. The main point is in the upper bound introduced as:
$$
x^{\top}Ax = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \tilde{x}_i^2
\le \max \lambda(A)\sum_{i=1}^n \tilde{x}_i^2
$$

and this is correct.

However, this proves only that
$ x^{\top}Ax \le \max \lambda(A),$ but not the original statement
$$ \max_{x : ||x||_2 = 1} x^{\top}Ax = \max \lambda(A)$$

Comment: The usual Lagrange multipliers proof (on the unit sphere) shows that at a maximum point $x$ (which must occur by compactness and continuity), $Ax=\lambda x$ for some constant $\lambda$. This, of course, means that $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: This exactly clarifies it! Many thanks. Only a true mathematician could answer this, and I'm not the one :)

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to check out my various lectures on YouTube (linked in my profile) on multivariable calculus and linear algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mazimize $x^TAx$, s.t. $x^Tx=1$. Using Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ we have 
$$
\arg\max_{x}( x^TAx - \lambda( x^Tx-1))
$$ 
so taking derivative w.r.t. vector $x$ and equating to zero we have 
$$
2Ax-2\lambda x=0 \to Ax=\lambda x.
$$ 
Namely, the set of solutions of this maximization problem should satisfy $ Ax = \lambda x$, i.e., such vectors $x$s are vectors that multiplying $A$ by $x$ is the same as multiplying $x$ by a scalar. That is, by definition $x$ have to be the eigenvectors and thus   $\lambda$ its corresponding eigenvalue. Now, you have a set of solutions $\{(\lambda_i, x_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ and you have to choose the pair the maximize the original function, so clearly $\max x^TAx = x ^T \lambda_{\max} x = \lambda_{\max} x^T x = \lambda_{\max}.$

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is symmetric, then its eigenvalues are real. Moreover, we have (Rayleigh coefficient)
$$
\frac{x^TAx}{||x||^2} = \lambda
$$
and since $||x||^2=1$, we get $x^T A x = \lambda$. So, 
$$
\max_{||x||^2 = 1} x^T A x = \max \lambda.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about this statement "then realized that only the strict inequality is justified in front of the upper bound."?

Take for example $A=I$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I clarified the question, could you please respond to it.

Comment: I second the answer above !